# How to run a non-OTP Erlang application on a remote server with nohup?

Tags: erlang, nohup

I have an Erlang code file which is not an OTP application. I do not use rebar.

My Erlang script just does some calculations and writes result to the file `result.txt`.

As the running time can be long, I would like to use `nohup` to run it on a remote machine.

However, running

```
nohup erl -noshell -pa ebin -eval "my_script:my_fun(Arg1,Arg2)" -s init stop &
```

does not do anything: `nohup.out` is created, but remains empty and `result.txt` is not created at all.

The same command without `nohup`

```
erl -noshell -pa ebin -eval "my_script:my_fun(Arg1,Arg2)" -s init stop
```

works, creating the `result.txt` file and returning ok.

How can I run my_script.erl through `nohup`?

Comment: Just a random guess: does it work if you use `-noinput` instead of `-noshell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use in your command line the option `-detached`

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html search about "detached"